# Why can't I print more than one string?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I can print one string. But when I try to add two strings it only prints the first string? curr is the beginning of the linked list. If I add one country and tell the program to print it will print the country with the information. However if I add two countries, It will only print the first country.

```
 void LinkedList::printList()
 {
    curr = head;
    while (curr)
    {
        cout << "Country Name: " << curr->name << ", " << "Gold: "  << curr->
        gold << ", " << "Silver: " << curr->silver << ", " << "Bronze: " << curr->bronze << "\n";
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

bool LinkedList::addCountry(string newName, int gold, int silver, int bronze) {
    if (head == NULL)// Adding first element
    {
        head = new struct Country;
        if (head == NULL) return false; // could not create head linked list country
        head->name = newName;
        head->gold = gold;
        head->silver = silver;
        head->bronze = bronze;
        head->next = NULL;
        return true;
    } else {
        curr = head;
        while (curr) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr = new struct Country;
        if (curr == NULL)
            return false;
        curr->name = newName;
        curr->gold = gold;
        curr->silver = silver;
        curr->bronze = bronze;
        curr->next = NULL;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the second one ends up in the list correctly?

Comment: @AndrewL no you don't need that.

Comment: Can we see how do you add the string to your linked list?

Comment: yeah, one moment please

Comment: @helllo please edit your question and add your functions in it and not in the comments, because it is a mess.

Comment: You're not adding the new country at all in your `else` block. Also, this looks like a mixture of C and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printList` is correct. But in `addCountry` the last element must point to the new element which was just inserted. For example:

```
bool LinkedList::addCountry(string newName, int gold, int silver, int bronze) 
{
    Country *newNode = new Country;
    newNode->name = newName;
    newNode->gold = gold;
    newNode->silver = silver;
    newNode->bronze = bronze;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        //adding first element:
        head = newNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        //find the last element currently in the list:
        Country *last = head;
        while (last->next)//<= ***** edited
            last = last->next;

        //set newNode as the new last element:
        last->next = newNode;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also in C++ you can simple write `new Country`, it doesn't need `struct` keyword.

Comment: When I try to add a second country it says the program stops working. Thanks for simplifying the problem a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

@Barmak Shemirani is correct. I think if you had a tail member it would be better:

```
  class LindedList
    {
    public:
        LindedList()
        {
            tail=head=curr=NULL;
        };
        Country* head;
        Country* curr;
        Country* tail;
     void printList()
     {
        curr = head;
        while (curr)
        {
            cout << "Country Name: " << curr->name << ", " << "Gold: "  << curr->
            gold << ", " << "Silver: " << curr->silver << ", " << "Bronze: " << curr->bronze << "\n";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    };

    bool addCountry(string newName, int gold, int silver, int bronze) 
    {
        curr = new Country;
        if (curr == NULL)
                return false;
        curr->name = newName;
        curr->gold = gold;
        curr->silver = silver;
        curr->bronze = bronze;
        curr->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = curr;
            tail=curr;

        } else 
        {
            tail->next=curr;
            tail=curr;

        }
        return true;
    };
    };
```